# Fastest way to check if dataframe is empty

Tags: r, dataframe, timing

What is the fastest (every microsecond counts) way to check if a `data.frame` is empty? I need it in the following context:

```
if (<df is not empty>) { do something here }
```

Possible solutions:

1) `if(is.empty(df$V1) == FALSE` from `spatstat' package

2) if(nrow(df) != 0)

3) Your solution

I could do:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(is.empty(df),times=100)
Unit: microseconds
         expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
 is.empty(df) 5.8 5.8  6.9      6 6.2  66   100
```

but not sure how to time 2). And what is your solution to empty df?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess more context is needed for this benchmark. `!nrow(df)` should be instant for almost any application.

Comment: I am wondering the definition of an empty data frame. It has 0 columns and rows or maybe it has length attributes `>= 0` but no data so only NULL, or maybe just NA?

Comment: The context is simple - I have a number of DFs that need to be used in the code. If DF is empty - continue to next one, if not - do smth in the code. `is.null` will not work as the object does exist.

Comment: @Frank is right (no surprise): with `df <- data.frame(x=1:5); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a=if (nrow(df)) 1 else 2, b=if(spatstat::is.empty(df)) 1 else 2)`, median of `nrow` is 5.355, median of `is.empty` is 17.627 (ms). Similar ratio of times with an empty data.frame.

Comment: I think it is also important to consider the operations on full (large) tables, as the operation will not only be considering the empty tables. I think this is why @Frank asked for more context.

Comment: On a table with 1e6 rows, the `is.empty` option is faster by half. You need to weigh the size and number of full tables vs. empty tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have two types of data.frames:

```
emptyDF = data.frame(a=1,b="bah")[0,]
fullDF  = data.frame(a=1,b="bah")

DFs = list(emptyDF,fullDF)[sample(1:2,1e4,replace=TRUE)]
```

and your `if` condition shows up in a loop like

```
boundDF = data.frame()
for (i in seq_along(DFs)){ if (nrow(DFs[[i]]))
  boundDF <- rbind(boundDF,DFs[[i]])
}
```

In this case, you're approaching the problem in the wrong way. The `if` statement is not necessary: `do.call(rbind,DFs)` or  `library(data.table); rbindlist(DFs)` is faster and clearer.

Generally, you are looking for improvement to the performance of your code in the wrong place. *No matter what operation you're doing inside your loop, the step of checking for non-emptiness of the `data.frame` is not going to be the part that is taking the most time.* While there may be room for optimization in this step, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" as Donald Knuth said.

Comment: What do you mean "you're looking at it the wrong way"?

Comment: @dayne I mean that they're looking for room for performance improvement in the wrong place. I edited to clarify. Also, "premature optimization is the root of all evil" as they say

Comment: Okay. I just found it a little confusing. It's a little more clear with your edit.

Comment: @Frank - you are absolutely right. While I could not solve the main problem - I've added this "patch" to the code that will save me some running time. But I am actively working on solution for the main time bottleneck. Thanks to ALL for discussion. Using `!nrow(df)` for now